# Character escaping in Pandoc filter pandoc.Para Lua function

Tags: string, lua, pandoc

I'm using Pandoc for a large HTML to Markdown conversion project and am trying to write lua filters to handle some of the special cases.

The most common case I am trying to handle is converting specially formatted information boxes into the pymarkdown [summary/detail formatting](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/details/).

**Source HTML**

```
<div class="special-info-block">
  <p class="title">INFO</p>
</div>
```

**Goal Markdown**

```
???+ info "INFO"
```

I can use this function to replace the "INFO":

```
function Div(el)
   if el.classes[2] == "special-info-block" and pandoc.utils.stringify(el.content[1]) == "INFO" then
      el.content[1] = pandoc.Para('??? info "INFO"+')
      return el
   end
end
```

but the resulting markdown escapes the quotation marks around INFO:

```
???+ info \"INFO\"
```

How do I insert the literal string instead? Is this a feature of the pandoc.Para constructor or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escaping happens during Markdown generation, so there are two options here:

1. Call pandoc with `-t markdown-smart`, which will instruct the Markdown writer to treat quotes as normal chars;
2. Create a raw Markdown block instead of a Para to get maximal control over the output: `el.content[1] = pandoc.RawBlock('markdown', '??? info "INFO"+')`.

Both methods these should give the desired result, but the second is probably preferable.

Comment: using `-t markdown-smart` worked perfectly! 

I had actually tried using `RawBlock` initially but when I do, I end up with this in my output:

\`\`\`{=markdown}<br/>
??? info "INFO"+<br/>
\`\`\`<br/>